# Twitter Search API The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, twitter, webclient, twitter-oauth

I have an app trying to make a simple GET call to a Twitter feed, but it;s failing with the error above. I am able to successfully get an access_token before calling the code below.

```
string lUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json&q=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("@typescriptlang");
var headerFormat = "Bearer {0}";
var authHeader = string.Format(
  headerFormat,
  Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(access_token)))
);
HttpWebRequest lRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(lUrl);
lRequest.Method = "GET";
lRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
WebResponse lResponse = lRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is exactly what you need to do, I have tested this and it is a working solution:

```
        private string oAuthConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oAuthConsumerKey"];
        private string oAuthConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oAuthConsumerSecret"];
        private string oAuthUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oAuthUrl"];     
        private static string searchFormat = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["searchFormat"];
        private string searchUrl = string.Format(searchFormat, "%23test");

        public string GetSearch()
        {
            // Do the Authenticate
            var authHeaderFormat = "Basic {0}";

            var authHeader = string.Format(authHeaderFormat,
                                           Convert.ToBase64String(
                                               Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthConsumerKey) + ":" +

                                                                      Uri.EscapeDataString((oAuthConsumerSecret)))

                                               ));
            var postBody = "grant_type=client_credentials";
            HttpWebRequest authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(oAuthUrl);

            authRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
            authRequest.Method = "POST";
            authRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
            authRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            using (Stream stream = authRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                byte[] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody);
                stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            }
            authRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
            WebResponse authResponse = authRequest.GetResponse();
            // deserialize into an object
            TwitAuthenticateResponse twitAuthResponse;
            using (authResponse)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(authResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    var objectText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    twitAuthResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwitAuthenticateResponse>(objectText);
                }
            }

            // Do the timeline
            HttpWebRequest timeLineRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(searchUrl);
            var timelineHeaderFormat = "{0} {1}";
            timeLineRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization",
                                        string.Format(timelineHeaderFormat, twitAuthResponse.token_type,
                                                      twitAuthResponse.access_token));
            timeLineRequest.Method = "Get";
            WebResponse timeLineResponse = timeLineRequest.GetResponse();

            var timeLineJson = string.Empty;
            using (timeLineResponse)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(timeLineResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    timeLineJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return timeLineJson;
        }
```

You also need to add this to the web or app.config in the appsettings:

```
<add key="searchFormat" value="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q={0}"/>
```

I will update my the GitHub project to include this later today at:

https://github.com/andyhutch77/oAuthTwitterTimeline

There will be some code to un-comment to display the search. I might have to re-think the project name now it has searching in it too.

Please note if it does not work you may have issues with the limit on your application at the twitter end. I have also read that some people have problems on shared IP adresses'.

Comment: Thanks for this I'll def try it and let you know.

Comment: Thanks, yes let me know. If the answer is no good I'll remove it so it doesn't send people down the wrong track.

Comment: Still failing with different error, 403 Forbidden. Sorry I don't know how to use Git so I just forked your project and added a file to root called DaveTwitterAttempt.cs. [link](https://github.com/dharric/oAuthTwitterTimeline)

Comment: I am using the search api on a publicly accessible profile. Does that matter?

Comment: Hi, No problem re: git, I usually just use 'git clone url' to copy it locally, it's a pretty handy command. Ok, the above has solved your issue of 401 because the first call must be authenticating you. It is the second call that differs and is forbidding access. If you leave it with me I will have a go around lunch time for you, in about 4hrs to see if I can get a working solution for you.

Comment: Hi, there is a working solution for you. Please accept and upvote my answer. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: I've changed the GitHub project so that it now includes the Search functionality. The project now called oAuthTwitterWrapper but the link is the same as above. The new functionality has been refactored into that sub-project so that new API calls can be added more easily. If you run the Console application you will see the search printed out too now.

Comment: I've changed the GitHub project so that it now includes the Search functionality. The project now called oAuthTwitterWrapper but the link is the same as above. The new functionality has been refactored into that sub-project so that new API calls can be added more easily. If you run the Console application you will see the search printed out too now.

Comment: Still getting the 403 on the timeLineRequest.GetResponse() line after the authentication is successful. I believe that its working for you. So it must be something either in my app or the urls I am using. My urls are https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token for auth and then https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json&q=@typescriptlang for search. I heard somethings about setting the callback url so I did set it to 127.0.0.1. My apps site url is set to my domain, but I'm doing this testing on my local machine.

Comment: Finally got it. My mistake I had an & instead of ? in start of my querystring parameter. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Excellent, you inspired me to change my projects name.